# How to define this summation in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to calculate this mathematical summation:

```
Σ(n=1 to 36) (C(36,n))*((-1)**(n+1))*0,23*(0,29**(n-1))
```

where 36 C n means the combination of these two numbers. I already got the function for that:

```
def C(n,k):
    C = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))
    return C
```

How can I make this summation?
I started learning Python this semester, and I happy to use it for the homework.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the result you are expecting from the sum?

Comment: A number less that 1, it's for a statistics homework :D

Comment: totally unrelated but you don't need the intermediate variable `C` in your `C` function - you can just `return factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))` - and if you really want to use an intermediate variable (ie for debugging reasons) please don't give it the same name as the function (not that it's a huge problem in this particular function but it could be in some cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you aim for something like this:

```
def C(n, k):
    return factorial(n)/factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)

sum([C(36,i)*((-1)**(i+1))*0.23*(0.29**(i-1)) for i in range(1,37)])
```

Comment: Why define `factorial` within `C` ??? And what makes you think the OP is asking for "how to define factorial" ?

Comment: Thank you, the last line is working very well.
Edit: Yes, I already defined the C, I imported the math module for this.
Thank you anyways!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sincerely I put it there for myself and forgot to remove it :) Do you think it's too much?

Comment: Having the factorial definition in the answer is not a problem in itself - I don't think the OP needs it but that's another problem. What bugs me is having it __within__ the `C` function's body - there's no need for a nested function here so it's unpythonic _and_ it will harm performances (inner function are created anew on each outer function call).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the detailed explanation, I removed the definition part as it clearly is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

How about `sum(map(lambda n: (C(36,n))*((-1)**(n+1))*0,23*(0,29**(n-1)), range(1, 36+1)))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to sum all the values into a single variable.

```
val = 0
for n in range(1,37):
    intrm_val = C(36,n))*((-1)**(n+1))*0,23*(0,29**(n-1))
    val = val + intrm_val
```

Do the same by using list comprehension like this:

```
intrm_val_list = [C(36,n))*((-1)**(n+1))*0,23*(0,29**(n-1)) for n in range(1,37)]
val = sum(intrm_val_list) # sum is built-in function of python.
```

Lambda is similar to inline functions.

```
def foo(a):
    return a*a
```

This above function can be easily be rewritten like this `lambda a : a*a`. Isn't this amazing !! We can rewrite our list comprehension using lambda like this

```
lambda n : C(36,n))*((-1)**(n+1))*0,23*(0,29**(n-1))
```

`map` is again a built-in function in python for applying a single function to multiple elements of an iterable( list in our case) simultaneously.
e.g. `map(func1, list_of_values)`.

`range` produces a generator within a given range, excluding the end element.
Combining all of the above information we get the answer given by another good fellow @Solomon Ucko.

Comment: That's why we have `sum(iterable[, start_value=0])` - which does the same thing but much faster and which less code ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers OP is new to python. Let us help him in building his skillset one step at a time. :-)

Comment: the OP obviously has some maths background so I don't think high-level functional programming style idioms will be a problem for him.  Also learning a language is not only learning it's syntax but also it's idioms, and the idiomatic solution here is definitly to use `sum()`.